# About debug UI of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

[image]

When an **exeption** dialog pops up,which line actually has/**triggers** the problem, the line hinted by green arrow or the line above?

Is there any official reference for this corner case?

**UPDATE**

So far it still seems that both are possible.Can anyone come up with a final conclusion?

Comment: Please someone give me an upvote so that I can paste image in it.

Comment: That's a hard question to answer generally. It depends. The immediate problem is pointed to by the line with the green arrow, but it was probably caused by code executing before. I suspect this is not the answer you are looking for though.

Comment: I'm not meaning which **caused**, but which **triggered**,to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to assembly window you will see exactly at what machine instruction the code is. If it is immediately after some call instruction then the exception happened inside that call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the microsoft reference links for Visual Studio Debugging UI

[Debugging UI Reference VS.Net 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwzf7x3e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[Using the Debugger : a Roadmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

This [Link from the msdn Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee410778.aspx) says that the current stack frame is indicated by a green curved tail arrow (while the active stack frame retains the yellow arrow).

Comment: Isn't the current frame and the active frame the same thing?

Comment: It can be different. See the blogpost of a former MVP http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Active-And-Current-Stack-Frame-And-Thread.aspx . He has detailed about stackframes and threads.

Comment: Then does the graph in my question means the problem is triggered by the active frame or current frame?

Comment: It was caused by whatever was in process of being executed by that statement.  It's green because it's from external code.  If you look at the call stack you'll see which command (in your code) was being executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's an official documented statement on this, but for me it seems to point to the line that triggered the exception.

But I wouldn't be too surprised if in some more complex situations (or if a release build is being debugged) that the debugger might get a bit confused and point to the incorrect location. I'd imagine that if that happens for a debug build, MS would consider it a bug, and might even fix it if reported in a reproducible scenario.

Comment: But IIRC,the green arrow points to the next statement **to be executed** in other cases,which is not already run.

Comment: But if a statement caused an exception, then it hasn't been successfully run. However, you certainly could be right that I'm forgetting some exception(s) that are handled specially for some reason. Also, there are settings which affect *when* the debugger will present an exception to you - either when it's first thrown or only if uncaught after having run though all the possible handlers.  Though it should still present these on the same line.

Comment: Forgot to mention that `FlashPlayer.exe` is adobe's product, not built from the project which contains the source above.Do you have any other idea with this in mind?